# If krull dimension is $0$, then all prime ideals are maximal?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, If we assume '$R$'s all prime ideals are maximal',then we can say $R$'s krull dimension is exactly $0$. This is easy because there are two different prime ideal $p$ and $q$ which satisfies $p⊂q⊂R$, and this contradicts the fact that $p$ is maximal.

But is the converse true?

my attempt:
If there are prime ideal $p$ which is not maximal,
then there are another ideal $q$ which satisfies $p⊂q⊂R$. If I can deduce $q$ is prime ideal, the proof are done.But I cannot show $q$ is a prime ideal.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does 'contain' mean 'properly contain'? If it does not so, the proposition cannot be used here.

Comment: $p$ *should* be maximal so there shouldn't be any proper ideals that properly contain $p$. On the other hand there is some maximal ideal that contains $p$ and if that's $p$ then you're good and if that's not $p$ then the Krull dimension can't be $0$.

Comment: I understood, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075283/every-ideal-is-contained-in-a-maximal-ideal).

Basically you need to verify that Zorn's lemma applies. If you have a chain of ideals that all contain $p$ and all don't contain $1$ then their union contains $p$ and doesn't contain $1$ (every chain has an upper bound). So the set of proper ideals containing $p$ contains a maximal element and that element is a maximal ideal.

2. Every maximal ideal is prime.

Which should be familiar.